# Generate random password for postgresql in bash

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql, shell, debian

I am trying to install postgresql and generate a random password for it on deployment, just for testing. Something like this:

```
$DBPASS=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1)
sudo -u postgres -H createuser --no-createrole --no-superuser --no-createdb $NAME
sudo -u postgres -H createdb -O $PROJECT $PROJECT
sudo -u postgres -H psql -c "alter user $PROJECT with password '$DBPASS'"
```

The error I get back is this:

> =b3wDxlSbUymho0CmOZ4TgPylLCanKdgJ: command not found                      /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/createdb: option requires an argument --
>   'O'                               Try "createdb --help" for more
>   information.
>   ERROR:  syntax error at or near "with password"
>   LINE 1: alter user  with password ''

Can anyone please explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first line needs to be altered (variables assignments should not have a dollar sign):

```
DBPASS=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1)
```

The error also suggests that `$PROJECT` is not being set - what do you get if you add `echo "$PROJECT - $DBPASS"` after the first line?

Comment: Thank you. The second error was because I hadn't set $project